# Prevent spacing in sub or super scripts with eulervm

Tags: fonts, math-mode, spacing, subscripts

When typing formulas to explain physics, sometimes non spaced text in super or subscripts is helpful.

```
$q_{heat}$
```

To prevent spacing in subscripts, I often used `\textit` in math mode:

```
$q_{\textit{heat}}$
```

since I use classic thesis together with `eulervm`, the `\textit` trick doesn't work any more, because text font changes.

Is there a better way to prevent spacing without changing the font?

How do I define a `\texteulervm` environment correctly?

---

As an example what happens, the following code:

```
j_{WDR,runoff}^{w} & \ne j_{\text{WDR,runoff}}^{w}
```

results in:
[image: FontChange]

please note the difference in the subscript.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You shouldn't be using Euler for those subscripts, because they are text, not math variables.

Comment: for Euler use `\text{..}` with package `amsmath`. Euler has no italic font

Comment: @ereg thx for the welcome, but using another font would clearly break the classic thesis layout; also spacing makes a great difference, and worked well over the last years...

Comment: @Herbert `amsmath` is already in use, but `\text{...}` also changes the font, it is clear that euler is non italic, the code above was just an example how I did it before using `eulervm` and `classic thesis`

Comment: `\text` uses the text font which is Euler. What do you mean by "changes the font"?

Comment: @Herbert, added an example in the question, problem stays the same when using `\textrm`

Comment: @StVO I don't think it breaks the layout; it rather breaks long established typographic rules related to mathematical typesetting.

Answer (score 3):

Not a solution according to your wishes, but it is according to well established standards.

The purpose of using Euler for math is to get a sharp visual distinction between text and math: letters for variables and digits are very different from any text font.

On the other hand, ‘WDR’ and ‘runoff’ are *not* math variables, but *specifiers* for distinguishing between variables with the same name. Just like they should be typeset upright when not using Euler, they should be upright and in the text font also with it. It's a similar situation as with function names such as ‘log’ or ‘sin’ that should be typeset in the *text* font and not in Euler.

A hypothetical `$j_{WDR}$` means *j* subscripted with the product of *W*, *D* and *R*, while `$j_{\textnormal{WDR}}` means what you really intend: the variable *j* subscripted with the *label* WDR.

Also your habit of typing `$j_{\textit{heat}}$` is wrong, according to the standards: it should be `$j_{\textnormal{heat}}$`, at least if ‘heat’ is a label and not a variable taking a value.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `$j_{\textnormal{heat}}$`, _etc._ with a braced subscript?

Comment: @JosephWright The `\text...` commands start with a `\bgroup`.

Comment: Yes, but if you are parsing formal LaTeX syntax then `_` and `^` take a single argument: `_\textnormal` may break with for example `breqn`.

Comment: @JosephWright I don't care about `breqn`; but I'll edit the code anyway. ;-)

Comment: @egreg: "It's a similar situation as with function names such as ‘log’ or ‘sin’ that should be typeset in the text font and not in Euler." I totally agree with that, it seems the most logical to me. But then why does *amsopn.sty* package use a mathcode variant of `\mathrm` instead of `\textnormal` for defining the macros `\operatorname` and `\DeclareMathOperator`? Is the AMS standard for function names wrong in this area?

Comment: @Maggyero That's for typesetting `-` as a hyphen, for instance, and not a minus sign.

Comment: @egreg: I know, but you said "function names such as ‘log’ or ‘sin’ that should be typeset in the ***text** font*", so why don't they use `\textnormal` instead?

Comment: @Maggyero Because that wouldn't be a math font and wouldn't obey to `\boldmath`, for one thing.

Comment: @egreg: Alright now I understand: when you said "function names such as ‘log’ or ‘sin’ that should be typeset in the *text* font", you meant in the text font *for math mode* (e.g.,`\mathit`), not in the text font *for text mode* (e.g., `\textit`). I've just realized that in theory `\mathnormal`, `\mathit` and `\textit` should result in *3* different fonts being used, for instance *Cambria Math*, *Cambria* and *Palatino* respectively. That concept of 2 fonts for *math mode* (one math font, and one text font that may differ from the text font for *text mode*) is a little hard to understand.

Answer (score 1):

define a command `\texteuler`:

```
\def\texteuler#1{{\fontencoding{U}\fontfamily{zeur}\selectfont\text{#1}}}
```

Comment: Well this fixed the font issue but the spacing stays like without the `\text`; probably an enclosed spacing is not defined for eulervm at all?

Comment: eulervm is a _math_ font

Comment: ok, I didn't know that spacing in math mode is done by the font itself, but it makes sense, I wrote an email to the package provider, if he knows/has another solution or if I have to create a new font